# Strange set locale behaviour when ssh from Windows PuTTY to Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, putty, localization

Please,
can someone shed some light on this strange locales related warning annoying me since I installed my server half year ago. It's  a variant of "Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale", which seems to be a pretty common issue, but mine has a strange twist, not matching any of the cases I found previously reported.

This warning is printed immediately after I log in with PuTTY on Windows to my Linux server.

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_GB.UTF-8,LANG=en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_GB.UTF-8,LANG=en_US.UTF-8)
```

Same happens when I use `ssh` command from Git Bash. When I log using VNC and open Konsole in KDE, Bash opens without any of these warnings.

What is unique to my case is the value it tries to set LC_CTYPE: `en_GB.UTF-8,LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. It looks like two concatenated strings. How this happened!?

This is original output on server side

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8,LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
...
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Note that:
1) all variables are set except LC_ALL - is that normal?
2) LC_CTYPE has the strange "concatenated" value
3) All values has quotes around except LC_CTYPE
4) warning is similar but complaining also about LC_ALL

I tried to fix it by editing `~/.profile`, on the server side, by appending:

```
export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Now, after re-logging, the locale seems to show reasonable values and no warnings from locale command:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
...
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

*Should I worry about some values not having quotes around them?*

But the login warning is still there, still pulling `en_GB.UTF8,LANG=en_US.UTF-8` from somewhere:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_GB.UTF8,LANG=en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_GB.UTF8,LANG=en_US.UTF-8)
```

Linux server: "openSUSE Leap 15.0"
Windows client 1: PuTTY 0.70
Windows client 2: Git Bash 2.21.0 (MinTTY terminal)

Any ideas?

[image: PuTTY just after logging in showing LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale warning]
[image: ssh in Git Bash just after logging in showing LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale warning]

Comment: What happens if you unset `LC_ALL`?

Comment: `LC_ALL` was unset at the beginning, to the best of my understanding. Or did you mean explicitly unset it with a specific command? Would it make difference?

Comment: I stopped setting `LC_ALL` in my `~/.profile`, it looks like its normal that it's not set. I set only `LC_CTYPE` and `LANG` ..and still the warning is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, end of mystery. Problem was in file `/etc/locale.conf`. It had just one strange line:

```
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8,LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

When I changed it to:

```
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

..warning disappeared!

Looks like openSUSE bug; most likely some system upgrade screwed this file, turned line end to a comma. I got a good help on this [openSUSE forum](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/535174-Strange-set-locale-behaviour-when-ssh-from-Windows-PuTTY-to-Linux).

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment.)

Is /etc/ssh/sshd_config in Linux the following line?

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Comment: Yes, I have `AcceptEnv LANG LANG LC_CTYPE` in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. And I also have `SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE` in my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` if that is of any importance.